# Laying out views in a TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to manually (programmatically) lay out views in a UITabBarViewController. I instantiate my UITabBarViewController like this:

MYAppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    MYViewController1 *myViewController1 = [[MYViewController1 alloc] init];
    myViewController1.title = @"My VC 1";
    [tabBarController addChildViewController:myViewController1];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

    return YES;
}
```

MYViewController1.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myView = [[MYView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:_myView];
}
```

MYView.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect descriptionRect, buttonRect;
    CGRectDivide(self.frame, &buttonRect, &descriptionRect, 50.f, CGRectMaxYEdge);

    _descriptionTextView.frame = descriptionRect;
    [self addSubview:_descriptionTextView];

    _myButton.frame = buttonRect;
    [self addSubview:_myButton];
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I get to `layoutSubviews`, the superview's frame is the full size of the window, so the button is hidden by the tab bar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With a clean project and copy/paste your code, I've got black screen. Please, edit your question and provide full code for classes (MYAppDelegate, MYViewController1, MYView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more code, it appears that you may have some confusion about the use of a UITabBarController.

In the code you have posted above you are initializing a UITabBarController, then a UIViewController, and then you are calling 'addChildViewController:' on the tabBarController. (however, addChildViewController: is an instance method on UIViewController).

Is this in attempt to add the ViewController as a tab of the TabBarController?  If so, then try the following code in place of addChildViewController: to see if it gives you the functionality that you are looking for:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[myViewController1]; // Passing an array of viewControllers will set them as a tabs on the TabBar in the order they are added to the array.
```

If that doesn't help, then please comment on this answer with more details regarding the desired functionality of your code, and I'll update my answer to assist you as much as I can.

EDIT:  Looks like I may have misunderstood your problem.  Can you try the following code in play of your subview's initialization:

```
_myView = [[MYView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; // Try bounds instead of frame.
```

Comment: I made those changes, and still the same result.

Comment: I tried using the bounds instead, and I still have the same problem. It looks like the view of my view controller's bounds is the full height of the window. So part of the view is obscured by the tab bar on the bottom of the window.

Comment: I think that my problem is that the view's bounds that the tab bar controller gives to its child view controllers extends under the tab bar by default (except for nav controllers). I just have to get the height of the tab bar and manually subtract that from my view.

Comment: That sounds correct.  I'm guessing you are developing targeting iOS 7, which would be why your view's frame extends behind the tab bar.  If you were using Nibs/Storyboards, then you could configure your autolayout to take care of that.  However, since it appears that you are doing it programmatically, subtracting the height of the tabBar should do the trick.